# Bot with gpg encrypting

Tags: python, xmpp, gnupg

I am creating some bot on python and I want to send encrypted message him from different instant messaging clients, e.g Miranda IM, QIP etc. For this issue I use [python-gnupg](http://packages.python.org/python-gnupg/index.html#index-1002) library for generating public and private keys. As I understand it is necessary to send public key to remote users. I can't simply send this key to an user, because i don't know which user connect to the bot. So, I think, it would be good to send the public key to servers where the bot is connected to, for example, jabber.org, icq.com etc.
How can I do it? Or, are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

You could upload your public key to the MIT public key server (http://pgp.mit.edu/).  They do not provide an API, but the HTML interface would be quite easy to drive from Python using `urllib` and some simple regexp searching.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the vCard system of Jabber to publish its identity in its own vCard available from the XMPP server directory for all XMPP clients.
You might put it in the 'About' field of the vCard for example

You can inspire yourself from that
http://yabfog.com/blog/2009/06/03/xmpp-vcard-python-script